# Создание тестового блочного устройства

Tags: linux, bash

В одной из статей увидел такой пример создания тестового блочного устройства:

```bsh
dmsetup create zero1 --table "0 $size zero"
```

При выполнении от root'а (т.е. проблем с доступом нет) вылезает следующая ошибка:

```bsh
Invalid format on line 1 of table
Command failed
```

Если же выполнять от обычного пользователя вылезает следующая ошибка:

```bsh
/dev/mapper/control/: open failed: Permission denied
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.145 (2017-11-03) and kernel driver (unknown version).
Command failed
```

При этом если указать размер устройства напрямую, то всё проходит:

```bsh
root # dmsetup create 1gb-zero --table '0 1953125 zero'
```

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить **в чём в принципе смысл $size** и почему в данном случае **не работает**?

P.S. Перед этим загружается kernel module, но что с ним, что без него ничего не меняется. В теле модуля ядра ничего, связанного с $size нет.

Comment: ээм, дык, я могу конечно ошибаться, но мне кажется `$size` это ж просто переменная которая должна определяться где-то ранее. Может та статья в которой Вы это нашли просто не оч хорошая?

Comment: @nobody, возможно ли использовать переменную из загруженного ранее модуля ядра или нужно определить её где-то в среде bash?

Comment: Я, если честно, вообще не понимаю о каких "переменных из модуля ядра" идёт речь, но можно обратиться к оф. документации и увидеть там примерно Ваш случай, где есть переменная `$TEN_TERABYTES` которую просто определяют в bash ДО `dmsetup ` : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/zero.txt

Comment: Если пример, приведенный вами идет как однострочник, то `$size` експортируется до этого. Например `export size=1234`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была действительно в том, как верно заметили @Hellseher и @nobody в необходимости экспорта переменной size до выполнения команд. Также можно, например, ввести переменную размера существующего файла:

```bsh
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
```